# Regular Expression for numbers and letters but not only numbers

Tags: python, regex

I have this string :

```
S3UPLOAD:Uploading file: /var/mobile/Applications/999445D0-5B4D-4078-9B81-4F65D3474971/Documents/2014-08-25 Driving 22.58.39/2014-08-25 Driving 22.58.39.vmd.zip 783:00
```

I would like find a regex that will match only substrings like `S3UPLOAD:` but not `783:`.
Substrings may contain either capital letters and numbers or capital letters only, not the number(s) only.

Tried this this exp.

```
/[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+:/
```

but its not efficient, as it will also match `783:` substring.

Comment: Are you sure the regex `[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+:` matches `783:`?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex to match the substrings which contain either capital letters and numbers or capital letters only, not the number(s) only.

```
[A-Z0-9]*[A-Z][0-9][A-Z0-9]*:|[A-Z]+:
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nW4yD9/7)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "S3UPLOAD:Uploading file: /var/mobile/Applications/999445D0-5B4D-4078-9B81-4F65D3474971/Documents/2014-08-25 Driving 22.58.39/2014-08-25 Driving 22.58.39.vmd.zip 783:00"
>>> m = re.search(r'[A-Z0-9]*[A-Z][0-9][A-Z0-9]*:|[A-Z]+:', s).group()
>>> m
'S3UPLOAD:'
```

Answer (score 1):

Covers capital letters only, and mixed with numbers. But must contain a capital.

`[A-Z0-9]*[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*:`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
 /([A-Z]*[0-9]*[A-Z]+)+/
```